# Border disrupted by unicode string displayed with waddwstr()

Tags: macos, unicode, ncurses, curses

After removing leading space the border isn't disrupted (it's only overwritten, and I can workaround that by creating additional window). In general, there's an interplay between amount of display width `1` and display width `2`  characters (Asian characters have width `2`), and also between parity of starting cursor position. If some overall parity isn't fulfilled, the border gets disrupted when a char is printed near it. This is on `OS X El Captain`, `libncurses.5.4.dylib`. On `Ubuntu` this problem doesn't exist.

```
wchar_t helloStr[] = L" <asian character1><asian character2>...";
wmove(stdscr, 3, 3);
waddwstr(stdscr, helloStr);
wborder(stdscr, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

What can be done to workaround this?

PS. Stackoverflow blocked posting when I entered actual Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1):

The file `libncurses.5.4.dylib` is ncurses [5.7.20081102](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20081102), which is rather old (actually not as old as some of the software bundled in OSX).  In the past 7 years, there have been a few fixes for double-width characters, e.g., [20140823](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#index-t20140823).

If you want to develop with ncurses on OSX, your best route would be to install add-ons such as MacPorts.

Comment: The workaround is to build with a current version of ncurses (and report any remaining bugs, of course - Apple's base install does not get updated often).